# Pagination: should I cache the next pages?

Tags: jquery, performance, caching, pagination

I have a PHP Web application with several results per item category. Hence, I implemented a *pagination with jQuery* to minimize the data loaded when loading page i-th from page j-th (but this aspect is not important at all).

The question is very simple: should I cache the next results by using such an hidden call (e.g. with an *Ajax call*) to my Web server? 
The benefits seems to be clear (faster response on user click). Are there such drawbacks?

Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a different approach. You may try the following steps;

1. Do an AJAX request (for first time) to call the second page when page loads (in document ready function).
2. Store the return data in a variable.
3. On second request, clear the HTML and append the field with AJAX data.
4. All `next` clicks should do an AJAX request and save the result in a variable.
5. The same must be done for `prev` clicks also.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. I have no problem with implementation. I just want to know if caching has sense, if there are real advantages and if some risks is hidden. E.g., what happen if the user click on the "next" button while an ajax call is just sent to the server? Is there any possibile slowing down of the performance?

Comment: you need not use cache coz it has no role and may affect memory. When user clicks next, the next page will be loaded immediately, and an ajax request will be sent in background. Enough time will be there to store received ajax data into a variable since user will take some time to read the loaded page.

Comment: So, do you definitively suggest to cache or not to cache the next page in a variable?

Comment: I recommend you to cache (store) the next page in a variable. I believe its OK in your case.